# Getting syntax error in SQL Server - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could anyone help me with this please?

```
CREATE TABLE CARRERA
(
     NOCARRERA CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
     CARRERA VARCHAR(30),
     CHECK (NOCARRERA LIKE 'C[0-9][0-9]')
)
```

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CHECK'

Comment: Just a tip, use integer instead of char(3) for the pk column.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of CHECK in SQL Server is as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],

  ...

  CONSTRAINT constraint_name
    CHECK [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ] (column_name condition)

);
```

So your query will look like,

```
CREATE TABLE CARRERA(
   NOCARRERA CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
   CARRERA VARCHAR(30),
   CONSTRAINT CHK_NOCARRERA CHECK (NOCARRERA LIKE 'C[0-9][0-9]')
)
```